# How to modify the file mfg_config.csv and add the relevant paths for all the files in aws edukit tutorial?

Tags: python, iot, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot, flashing

I'm trying to Set up AWS IoT Certificates Flashing Espressif Certificates in the espalexacredencials folder, but I'm having the error:

espalexacredentials % python $IDF_PATH/components/nvs_flash/nvs_partition_generator/nvs_partition_gen.py generate /path/to/mfg_config.csv mfg.bin 0x6000

python $IDF_PATH/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip esp32 --port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART write_flash 0x10000 mfg.bin

python: can't open file '/components/nvs_flash/nvs_partition_generator/nvs_partition_gen.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file '/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can someone help me explain the steps to modify the file mfg_config.csv and add the relevant paths for all the files ? I think I'm not doing it in the right way

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to modify the mfg_config.csv file. If you clone/rebase the latest code from the [Core2 for AWS IoT EduKit repository](https://github.com/m5stack/Core2-for-AWS-IoT-EduKit), you do not need to modify that file: https://edukit.workshop.aws/en/intro-to-alexa-for-iot/flashing-espressif-certificates.html

If you want to continue using the version you have, you need to replace the "/path/to" with the directory location that the file is located in. For example, if I had downloaded and extracted the zip in my user's download folder, it would look like this:

```
/Users/rashedtalukder/Downloads/espcredentials/mfg_config.csv
```